# Using HoTT, why is twisted cohomology of BG group cohomology?

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology, homotopy-type-theory

I've been reading [Michael Shulman's](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2013/08/08/spectral-sequences/) blog posts defining cohomology in homotopy type theory, and I'd like to understand (using HoTT) why cohomology of BG is group cohomology.

if I understand correctly, given a parametrized spectrum (i.e. a fibration by spectra) $E: X \to \mathsf{Spectra}$, we define the twisted cohomology of $X$ with coefficients in $E$ to be $H^n(X; E) \equiv \Vert \prod_{x:X} \Omega^{-n} E_0 \Vert_0$.

In particular, if we have a parametrized family $V: X \to \mathsf{AbGroup}$ then we can compose with the Eilenberg-MacLane construction $H: \mathsf{AbGroup} \to \mathsf{Spectra}$ to get a parametrized family of Spectra  $HV: X \to \mathsf{Spectra}$. The cohomology $H^n(X; HV)$ is cohomology with local coefficients, which is the twisted version of ordinary cohomology.

Now if we consider the case $X = BG$ (i.e. $BG=K(G,1)$ ) for $G$ a set-group, then a parametrized family $V: BG \to \mathsf{AbGroup}$ is the same as a group representation of $G$, since functions are functorial on paths in HoTT. In other words, given $g: \bullet = \bullet$, we get a path $g_*: V(\bullet) = V(\bullet)$. Now, if we consider the corresponding twisted cohomology $H^n(BG; HV) \equiv \Vert \prod_{x:BG} K(V(x);n) \Vert_0$, why do we get group cohomology?

For now let's just consider $H^0(BG; HV) \equiv \Vert \prod_{x:BG} V(x) \Vert_0 = \prod_{x:BG} V(x)$, where the second equality follows because $V(x)$ is a set. In order to get group cohomology, it should be the case that any $v:  \prod_{x:BG} V(x)$ encodes a $G$-invariant element of the $G$-representation. But it isn't immediately obvious to me why this should be the case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how to formalize this in HoTT but the idea is that an element of that product is an element v_x in V for every x in BG in such a way that for every path g:x->x' the corresponding isomorphism V to V identifies v_x with v_{x'}. In this case there is only one point, paths are elements of the group, and the corresponding isomorphism is acting by g. Thus this is exactly a G-invariant element of V. In particular that product may be the slickest way to say V^G in HoTT.

Comment: @JustinHilburn I wonder if you or a HoTT expert can leave an answer elaborating on "that product [is] the slickest way to say V^G in HoTT".

Comment: @Theo My understanding of HoTT is limited, but as far as I know semantically a type $X$ corresponds to a space,   and a family parameterized by $X$, say $F: X \to \mathcal U$ classifies a fibration over $E \to X$.   Then the formation of the $\Pi$ type  $\Pi_{x:X} F(x)$ is right adjoint to the pullback functor $Top \to Top/X$-- i.e. it is the global sections functor.  So Justin's statement should translate to the familiar fact that global sections over $BG$ correspond to taking $G$ invariants

Comment: Take a look also at the nLab page on group cohomology: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+cohomology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really much to say (which is why I'm marking this answer as CW):

As Phil Tosteson commented, forming $\Pi$-types is right adjoint to the constant family map $\mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U}^{BG}$ (and $\Sigma$-types gives the left adjoint). So that's the universal property of invariants (and co-invariants).

Perhaps it would help to see what happens if $G$ is a $1$-group: We can present $BG$ as a HIT with constructors
$$ \text{pt} : BG, \quad \text{loop} : G \to \text{pt}=\text{pt},\quad \text{loop-cmp} : \prod_{g,h:G}\text{loop}(g\cdot h) = \text{loop}(g)\cdot\text{loop}(h), $$
as well as a constructor forcing $BG$ to be a $1$-type. If $V : BG \to \text{Set}$ is any $G$-set, then by the universal property of $BG$ as a HIT, we get an equivalence
$$ \prod_{t:BG}V(t) \simeq \sum_{v:V(\text{pt})}\prod_{g:G}g\cdot v = v.$$
(Since $V$ is a family of sets, there's nothing to do for the $\text{loop-cmp}$ constructor.)